# 403 Page to Login Redirect for Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla

I have followed the steps from the this link: http://docs.joomla.org/Auto_redirect_guests_to_login

After I try to log in either as a guest or as admin, it gives me the 403 page. After I retry to login, I notice that it has already registered, but it cannot redirect to the correct page. In my case to the CREATE ARTICLE page.

In the beginning it worked for 2-3 logins. After that something happened and it doesn't work. I log in, it tries to redirect and fails, although it sees the redirection url. If I try to log in from the redirection link again, it prints AN INVALID TOKEN message. If I try to log in from log-in page again, it shows that I am already logged in.

Redirection doesn't see my logging, and because my redirection page is for registered users only, and the system doesn't recognize my logging, it prints the frustrating 403 page.

Comment: Is this helps ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907879/joomla-mod-login-redirect-using-get-username/18908544#18908544

Comment: Can you send a link or copy code?

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me more details in which file should i interfere and in which lin should i make adjastments and what?

Comment: A link no because it's underconstruction but i can send a copy code. Which part do you need?

Comment: Why don't you just make a nice error.php that matches your template and looks attractive and contains a login screen. The problem with redirecting to the actual login is that you will send an incorrect http status header. This is what those pages are for.  The core templates have them unless you are in 1.5 but it's the same concept in 1.5.

Comment: i AM USING JOOMLA 2.5. Ok how to make a nice error.php? What code should i edit/enter? Yew THAT'S the problem: incorrect http status header. How to fix it? Something jumbles and confuses it

Comment: I Have more news. I recreated my mebsite from scratch with a lot off backups. Everything working ok if i login as admin. When i create a user account and enter as user everything collapses. Then both user and admin get 403 after redirection. It's so crazy. What's the problem?